# How to pass command with its arguments as a single argument to script?

Tags: bash, variables, pipe, command-line-arguments

I have a script I use for building my kernel, and in it I have a function I want to use to catch errors in my build commands, but I can't figure out how to pass multiple arguments as one to get it working properly. The syntax is as follows:

```
run_build() {
cmd=$($1)
status=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
$*
if ($status != 0); then
    echo "$cmd failed!"
    exit 1
else
    echo "$cmd succeeded."
fi
}
```

The problem is, when I try to pass a `make` command with its arguments, the `make` command is being executed with no arguments. I tried to use the "$*" syntax to call all arguments but it doesn't seem to work. An example command would be

```
make O=out -j8 zImage
```

I need the next 3 arguments to be included when calling the line from the script. Anyone have ideas?

Comment: Just wrap the whole string in quotes...though I'm not sure this is a great idea.

Comment: Yeah, it is. As long as you don't wrap it again in the called script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First point, you don't want to pass the entire command as a single argument: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ#BashFAQ.2F050.I.27m_trying_to_put_a_command_in_a_variable.2C_but_the_complex_cases_always_fail.21)

This is the main error: `cmd=$($1)` -- the `$()` syntax invokes [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) that *executes* the first argument. Just use `cmd=$1` to store the first parameter into the "cmd" variable.

Additional errors:

- `if ($status != 0); then` -- that syntax is incorrect: use `if ((status != 0)); then` for proper arithmetic evaluation.
- `$*` -- to execute the positional parameters correctly, use `"$@"` (with the quotes) -- that form will maintain any arguments that contain whitespace as intended.

Comment: I recommend you paste your script into http://shellcheck.net to test for additional syntax errors.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by ANSI.

Comment: Traditionally we recommend `if [ "$status" != 0 ]` or in `ksh`/Bash `if [[ $status != 0 ]]` though arithmetic context also works ... but only for numbers, so the OP might get a new unpleasant surprise when they try to compare strings.

Answer (score 1):

The proper solution to this is probably something like

```
if "$@"; then
    echo "$@ succeeded" >&2
else
    rc=$?
    echo "$@ failed" >&2
fi
```

but this still seems like you are replacing perfectly good built-in functionality with something worse.

Answer (score 1):

Not fond of this setup for a few obvious reasons and few less obvious.

For the record, c.f. [this page on why not to do this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).
Also worthy of note, in case you shift to `eval`, which idealogically is kind of what this function is doing... [please read this too](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ#BashFAQ.2F048.Eval_command_and_security_issues).

...but for a simplistic solution -
Arguments come in as an array. If you are running the build, then make your function run the build, with ***quoted*** arguments.

```
run_build() {
  if make "$@"  # QUOTED, *explicit* call to make
  then echo "'make $@' succeeded."
  else echo "'make $@' failed."
       return 1 # exit in function only sets return - be explicit
  fi
}

run_build O=out -j8 zImage # run_build as a make synonym
```

Don't try to build do-anything functions.
That way lies madness.

If you *must* use other commands than make, then validate and verify.

```
run_build() {
  local cmd=$1
  shift
  case "$cmd" in
  make|or|some|other|specifically|ok|word)
    if "$cmd" "$@" # QUOTED!!!
    then echo "'$cmd $@' succeeded." 
    else echo "'$cmd $@' failed."
         return 1 
    fi 
  ;;
  *) echo "Invalid argument: '$cmd' not recognized."
     return 1
  ;;
  esac
}
```

If you aren't at least doing that, what's the purpose of the function? I mean, you are passing in all the parts of the command anyway, and not doing much with them beside executing them. Why not just...you know, execute them, instead of bothering with a function? But even if you keep it to it's simplest, quote, quote, quote.

```
run_build() { "$@" && echo "'$@' succeeded" || {
                      echo "'$@'failed; return 1; }; }
```

Comment: I appreciate your feedback, I'm fairly new to scripting still and wasn't aware of a simpler way of accomplishing this. Your suggestion is very appealing for its simplicity though so I'll try that in place of what I have now and see how that works for me. Thank you